# Postgresql - How to set variable value in function

Tags: postgresql, function, stored-procedures

I'm trying to set value of a variable based on case statement and return the data as a table in Postgres function.

In the case statement I'm trying to do bitwise operation on options
field

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_ticket_types()
  RETURNS TABLE (
    ticket_type   text   
  ,sale_type text) AS
$func$

declare sale_type text;
BEGIN


   RETURN QUERY

   select name::text as ticket_type, 
(case when (options & 1) > 0 then sale_type = concat(sale_type, 'POS ')
when (options & 2) > 0 then sale_type = concat(sale_type, 'Internet Jetstar ') 
when (options & 4) > 0 then  sale_type = concat(sale_type, 'Internet ')
when (options & 64) > 0 then  sale_type = concat(sale_type, 'Internet FAPAS ')
when (options & 128) > 0 then  sale_type = concat(sale_type, 'Internet Amadeus ')
when (options & 8) > 0 then sale_type = concat(sale_type, 'Agent ')
when (options & 16) > 0 then  sale_type = concat(sale_type, 'Kiosk-Credit ')
when (options & 32) > 0 then  sale_type = concat(sale_type, 'Kiosk-Cash ')
when (options & 32768) > 0 then  sale_type = concat(sale_type, 'Preprinted ')
 end )as sale_type

  from skybus_tickettype
 order by name asc;

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This is not working. Can anybody tell me what is wrong in this ?

It shows the following error

> ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type DETAIL:
>   Returned type boolean does not match expected type text in column 2.
>   CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function get_ticket_types() line 7 at RETURN QUERY
>   ********** Error **********

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a text function to get concatenated type names from options:

```
create or replace function get_sale_type(options int)
returns text language plpgsql as $$
declare
    sale_type text = '';
begin
    if options & 1 > 0 then sale_type:= concat(sale_type, 'POS '); end if;
    if options & 2 > 0 then sale_type:= concat(sale_type, 'Internet Jetstar '); end if; 
    if options & 4 > 0 then sale_type:= concat(sale_type, 'Internet '); end if;
    if options & 8 > 0 then sale_type:= concat(sale_type, 'Agent '); end if;
    if options & 16 > 0 then sale_type:= concat(sale_type, 'Kiosk-Credit '); end if;
    if options & 32 > 0 then sale_type:= concat(sale_type, 'Kiosk-Cash '); end if;
    if options & 64 > 0 then sale_type:= concat(sale_type, 'Internet FAPAS '); end if;
    if options & 128 > 0 then sale_type:= concat(sale_type, 'Internet Amadeus '); end if;
    if options & 32768 > 0 then sale_type:= concat(sale_type, 'Preprinted '); end if;
    return sale_type;
end $$;
```

and use it in this way:

```
select 
    name::text as ticket_type, 
    get_sale_type(options) as sale_type
from skybus_tickettype
order by name asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is getting error `ERROR: syntax error at or near "text"`, make sure that the function language is `plpgsql`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test()
    RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
declare
    some_variable text := 1;
BEGIN
...
```

Had the same problem